# Error al declarar ArrayAdapter como publico (global)

Tags: android, android-studio, arrayadapter

Tengo un error al declarar ArrayAdapter como publico (global),cuando lo hago dentro de un metodo funciona perfecto,pero como0 publico da el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me ayuda a resolverlo porfavor.

Comment: Puedes compartir cual es el error que te pasa, el error lo puedes ver en el log de Android Studio, así seria mas fácil ayudarte

Comment: Cual es el error que te lanza?

Comment: Las imágenes, no sólo hacen imposible copiar tu código para probarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluir el código y el mensaje de error como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionar el código completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacerlo publico declaralo de la siguiente manera:

```
 //Esto va donde lo tienes declarado ahora...
 public ArrayAdapter <String> adaptador = null;

 @public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstance){

    //Dentro del metodo
    adaptador = new AarrayAdapter(this, android.R.Layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);        
 }
```

Intentalo y comenta si te ha funcionado.